# Transformation of fractional constraint to convex/linear constraint in optimization problem

Tags: optimization

I have this constraint in an optimization problem:

$$\frac{a}{x_1} + \frac{b}{x_2} + \frac{c}{x_3} = d$$

where $x_i$ are the variables. Other than this my problem is linear. Is it possible to transform this constraint into a linear form?

Comment: Hi. Actually my constraint is: a/x1 + b/x2 + c/x3 <= d How do I transform this into a second-order cone problem?

Comment: This is a separable equation, so you may be able to use a lambda formulation to generate a piecewise linear approximation, depending on whether you're minimizing or maximizing.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Non-linear equality constraints are always non-convex, and as you have other linear constraints, you will probably not be able to make any clever variable change, as that will turn your other constraints non-linear and most likely non-convex instead.

However, depending on the sign of your coefficients, and the objective function, it could be that your problem can be written as a convex problem at least. If your objective is deceasing in $x$ (i.e. smaller $x$ better) and $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive, you can replace the inequality with $\leq$, as it will be tight at optimality. With that, you have a convex program (and if you want, you can write the fractional constraint using a second-order cone reformulation if you want, and thus solve it using second-order cone programming which is a slight generalization of linear programming, otherwise just use a standard nonlinear solver)

Comment: Hi. Actually my constraint is:

a/x1 + b/x2 + c/x3 <= d

How do I transform this into a second-order cone problem?

Comment: $x^{-1}\leq z$ is equivalent to $\left| \left|\begin{bmatrix}2\\z-x\end{bmatrix}\right| \right| \leq z+x$, and then you go from there

Comment: But I only think you can apply this if the constraint is a/x1 <= b, i.e. with a single variable. I cannot see how you can do it with more variables.

Comment: You have $az_1+bz_2+cz_3 \leq d$ where $x_i^{-1}\leq z_i$